# запрос в базу данных при помощи django объекта Q к одному полю с оператором &

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, queryset

Есть модель:

```
class Artikul_cabinets(models.Model):
     artikul_cabinets = models.CharField(verbose_name="Артикул шкафа", max_length=20)
     title_cabinets = models.CharField(verbose_name="Описание шкафа", max_length=200)
     width_cabinets = models.ManyToManyField(Width_cabinets)
     depth_cabinets = models.ManyToManyField(Depth_cabinets)
     unit_cabinets = models.ManyToManyField(Unit_cabinets)
     weight_cabinets = models.ManyToManyField(Weight_cabinets)
     type_cabinets = models.ForeignKey(Type_cabinets, default=1)
     color_cabinets = models.ForeignKey(Color_cabinets)
     glass_cabinets = models.ManyToManyField(Glass_cabinets)

class Meta:
     verbose_name_plural = "Артикул шкафа"

def __str__(self):
     return self.artikul_cabinets
```

Надо сделать отбор по полю:

```
glass_cabinets = models.ManyToManyField(Glass_cabinets)
```

Отбор делаю следующим образом:

```
data = Artikul_cabinets.objects.filter(Q(glass_cabinets=artgen['perf']) & 
                       Q(glass_cabinets=artgen['glass'])
```

И мне мне возвращается пустой `QuerySet`, хотя в БД элемент с параметрами `perf` и `glass` присутствуют в одной записи.

Подскажите что я делаю не так. Пробовал:

```
data = Artikul_cabinets.objects.filter(Q(glass_cabinets=artgen['perf']),
                       Q(glass_cabinets=artgen['glass'])
```

и тоже не работает, хотя если ставить оператор `|`, то условие "ИЛИ" отрабатывает нормально.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Как одно поле может одновременно равняться `artgen['perf']` и `artgen['glass']` (при условии, что `artgen['perf']` и `artgen['glass']` различны)?

Comment: `artgen['perf']` и `artgen['glass']` различны. Поле `glass_cabinets` имеет связь `ManyToManyField` с моделью `Glass_cabinets`. и соответственно в одной записи может быть несколько значений `glass_cabinets`. Или я что то не так понимаю. Пример - http://clip2net.com/s/3uqrPGX

Comment: Может быть проще будет выдернуть все `Artikul_cabinets` через обратную связь в объектах `Glass_cabinets`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решилась проблема так:

```
Artikul_cabinets.objects.filter(glass_cabinets=artgen['perf']).filter(glass_cabinets=artgen['glass'])
```